# Does zxms6004ff come with flyback diode internally?

Tags: diodes, flyback, mosfet-driver

As question above, does anyone know better about product from DIODES? I am using zxms6004ff, but not sure about if it comes with flyback diode internally? I read over their datasheet. It only says it is self protected and i email their North America Branch, no one reply me yet. I have no choice to replace to other MOSFET currently. Does anybody know? And if nobody sure about it, would it be possible to add flyback diode anyway no matter it has or not? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the datasheet doesn't say that it has a flyback protection diode, then assume that it doesn't have one.

Comment: An extra flyback diode will do no harm.

Answer (score 1):

It has over voltage clamping - up to 90mJ. You'll have to look at the power dissipation to see how frequently it can switch.

The MOSFET itself turns on to absorb much of the inductive energy.

If you add a diode across the inductance (not D-S) the MOSFET will not turn on from overvoltage, but the current will die off more slowly.